# Windows 8.1: UEFI to System Recovery not working

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, uefi

I'm currently restoring a Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2 10''. I used a previously created recovery drive to reinstall the original Windows 8.1, and let it repartition the disk. Everything seems to work so far, but: When I try to access "Recovery Mode" from the UEFI ("Novo Menu", Windows boots normally. Seems like the normal Windows partition is booted, not the recovery one.

**diskpart volumes**
`0  (C:)  NTFS   23GB    Start   System partition
 1        FAT32  100MB   System  UEFI
 2        NTFS   5992MB  Hidden  Windows-Images`

**reagentc /info**
`WinRE-Status:                          Enabled
WinRE-Ort:
Startkonfigurationsdaten-ID:           9ec487e5-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7
Ort des Wiederherstellungsimages:      \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition4\Windows Images
Index des Wiederherstellungsimages:    1
Ort des benutzerdefinierten Images:
Index des benutzerdefinierten Images:  0`

**bcdedit /enum all**
`Start-Manager für Firmware
Bezeichner              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                        {3f5c7215-5b4f-11e6-9727-806e6f6e6963}
                        {edd6bb31-5afb-11e6-9728-806e6f6e6963}
                        {3f5c7216-5b4f-11e6-9727-806e6f6e6963}
                        {3f5c7217-5b4f-11e6-9727-806e6f6e6963}
timeout                 2

Windows-Start-Manager
Bezeichner              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  de-de
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {9ec487d9-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
displayorder            {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

...

Firmwareanwendung (101fffff)
Bezeichner              {edd6bb31-5afb-11e6-9728-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Lenovo\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot PBR

Windows-Startladeprogramm
Bezeichner              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  de-de
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {9ec487e5-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {9ec487d9-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
detecthal               Yes

Windows-Startladeprogramm
Bezeichner              {9ec487e5-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
device                  ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume4]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{9ec487e6-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Recovery Environment
locale                  de-de
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessage          Recovery
osdevice                ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume4]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{9ec487e6-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

...

Geräteoptionen
Bezeichner              {9ec487e6-5af8-11e6-b566-e6392909e3c7}
description             Windows Recovery
ramdisksdidevice        partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi`

The really weird part: There is no `EFI\Lenovo` directory on volume 1, and the `Recovery` folder on volume 2 is empty. However, starting recovery from within Windows works fine. Seems like I have to correct the paths to `Windows-Images\custom.wim`, but I don't know how – Visual BCD Editor crashes when trying to edit a `ramdiskpath` or `device`.

Comment: After checking the Bootloader, it seems that `\EFI\Lenovo\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` is missing (complete Lenovo directory not there). Windows RE is located under disk0 volume2 (Windows Images\custom.wim), BCD entry is `Windows Boot PBR`.

Comment: You can use diskpart to map all unmapped partitions. Select disk, then partition, then assign drive letter. Visual BCD cannot edit paths on unmapped drives.

Comment: After you map EFI System when going through search/folder button in "edit application path" dialog for {bootmgr} you get a semi-explorer with admin rights where you can visually examine contents of partition/volume.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) to examine and edit full contents of BCD.

A recovery loader entry in BCD is like a normal loader but instead of partition devices it has LocateEx devices which point to a "recovery.wim" file.

If you don't want to go to BCD details you could use **ReagentC.exe** utility which can create a connection (recovery loader entry) in BCD to a recovery wim file. Read documentation for ReagentC.exe how to use it.

Comment: Visual BCD Editor does not work well for me, I always get "RELOAD STORE - BCD CHANGED IN EXTERNAL PROCESS". I cannot change the loader, changes are not saved. And in reagentc.exe: you mean via /setbootshelllink? Where do I get a corresponding file?

Comment: Use version 0.9.0.1. Message "RELOAD STORE - BCD CHANGED IN EXTERNAL PROCESS" could be ignored.